# svg element background image and bg color

Tags: html, svg, jquery-svg

I had a SVG in my application , there is a circle on that . I have to assign a background image ( png ) + background color + strike to that element. I got the code like follows for making bg image for that element. Please help me how to assign bg color + image

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="900" height="500"  id="holder"> 

    <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="40" height="40"  >
        <image xlink:href="test.png" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40"  />
    </pattern>

</defs>

    <circle cx="700" cy="200" r="20" fill="url(#img1)" id="goal" class="goal" z-index="1500" fill-opacity="1" >
 </circle>

 </svg>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the question.

Comment: My question is how to assign a SVG element background image + color like  in css    "background:url("images/bg.png") left top no-repeat #ccc;"

Comment: Have you found out how to do this? I'm trying to do the same, combine a background image as `.png`using `filter="url(...)"` and background color in the `fill=""`attribute, plus adding a drop shadow effect but cannot have the background-image working with anything else

Comment: No .. didn't solved the issue ... And some how I adjusted with CSS3 ....